# Code analysis warns about a potential of disposing of an object twice

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, code-analysis, streamwriter

Just ran a code analysis on one of the applications I inherited, and it raised warnings about code similar to the following:

```
using (StreamWriter tw = File.AppendText("Log.txt"))
{
    try
    {
        tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("------------------------");
        tw.WriteLine(data);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Error writing to the log file: {0}", ex.Message));
    }
    finally
    {
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

If I comment out the `finally` block, the warning is not raised. I was under impression that closing a stream writer only closed the underlying file, but did not actually dispose of the writer object. Is code analysis broken, or am I misunderstanding how stream writer should be used?

Here's another example where code analysis complains about possible disposing of both writer and the underlying stream twice:

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filename)))
{
    while (tr.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        counter++;
    }

    tr.Close();
}
```

It complains about both `tr` and `File.OpenRead(filename)`

Comment: `using` automatically disposes the instance created, you don't have to explicitly call `.Close()` or  `.Dispose()`. I suggest googling, how `using` works

Comment: Yes, `Close` calls `Dispose`. It's a weird API.

Comment: @o_O The question author stated that they thought that `Close` was different from disposal, not that a `using` doesn't dispose of the object.

Comment: First Google result: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close(v=vs.110).aspx - *This implementation of Close calls the Dispose method passing a true value.*.

Comment: @Servy I know that, I'm making the OP aware of `using`s functionality

Comment: @o_O So you're aware that the OP understand how `using` works, but you wanted to make them aware of something that they were already aware of because...why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Close just calls Dispose on the object](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,ab19992c30648b1d), so yes, you're disposing of the object twice.  (Not that disposing of an object twice is problematic, just redundant.)

Comment: Yes, I missed that part. Consistency, Microsoft? First they want us to wrap `IDisposable` in `using`, then this.